# Which is the correct way to analyse balls drawn from an urn (with replacement)

Tags: probability

4 balls are extracted at random - **with replacement** - from a urn with 3 white and 6 black balls. What is the probability that all extracted balls are 2 white and 2 black?

Here is all my steps:

> If we use this method like in [this video from 1:50](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=uKTjh-6PFjo) obtain:

- The probability that the ball extracted to be white is: $\frac{1}{3}\Rightarrow\left(\frac{1}{3}\right)^2$= probability that from 2 balls extracted, 2 are white;
- The probability that the ball extracted to be black is: $\frac{2}{3}\Rightarrow\left(\frac{2}{3}\right)\cdot\left(\frac{1}{3}\right)^2$= probability that from 3 balls extracted, 2 are white and 1 is black;

$$\Rightarrow\left(\frac{1}{3}\right)^2\cdot\left(\frac{2}{3}\right)^2 = \text{probability that from 4 balls extracted 2 are white and 2 are black}$$

> But if we use [Bernoulli trial](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bernoulli_trial) we obtain: $P={4\choose 2}\cdot\left(\frac{1}{3}\right)^2\cdot\left(\frac{2}{3}\right)^2$

Why if we use **Bernoulli trial** we have one more thing: ${4\choose 2}$? And which is correct from above?

Comment: $(\frac13)^2(\frac23)^2$ is the probability of drawing two white balls and two black balls **in that order:** white, white, black, black. (Did you hear the words "in that order" in the video?) The event "two white, two black" does not have to come in that order. In fact there are $\binom42$ possible orders: WWBB, WBWB, WBBW, BWWB, BWBW, BBWW.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The two solutions you found solve two different problems. In the first one you are requiring the four ball extracted to be: white, white, black, black in this precise order. In the second one you require them to be two white and two black with no precise order. The problem seems to require the second solution, so the second one should be the correct answer.

The factor $\binom{4}{2}$ is precisely the number of different ways in which two white and two black balls can be sorted out (choose two places among four).

Answer (score 4):

Binomial probability is the correct approach because you don't care about the order of sampling the balls: $\binom{4}{2}$ means 2 successes in 4 trials regardless of the order.

Answer (score 3):

The second is correct (4 independent Bernoulli trials) since the first argument doesn't allow for the $6=\binom{4}{2}$ orders in which you can get 2 w and 2 b balls, namely, bbww, bwbw, bwwb, wbbw, wwbb, wbwb.